# Does the tip selection depend on how quickly the proof of work is done?

Tags: transaction, pow, tip-selection

I read that the tip selection chooses the newest transactions with a higher probability than the older ones in the tangle. So I am afraid that my computer is too slow.

Do I have a better chance to get my transaction done if my computer is faster?

Comment: "tip selection chooses always the newest"  is wrong. Correct formulation would be "the tip selection algo have higher probability to select new tips"

Comment: Tip selection happens before you do the Proof of Work. You need the tips (trunk & branch transaction) to do the proof of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that tip selection generally favours newer transactions. So it is of benefit to finish your PoW quicker.

But unless your computer takes a couple minutes, this should not have a huge impact in practice.